# WCF restful service access denied when trying to upload file?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, file-upload, wcf-rest

I made a WCF restful service for uploading the files to specific directory on the server, and a small ASP.NET web application that can upload the files threw this web service. The problem is that I am constantly getting the error of access denied. I tried to give all the privileges to a folder for testing purposes (Full control for Everyone, Full control for IIS_IUSRS, AppPool of WCF and Web service, etc.), but still the same error shows. Below is the code of Service and Web application:

**Main WCF service class**

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
                 InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
                 IgnoreExtensionDataObject = true,
                 IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class UploadFile : IUploadFile
    {
        public ReturnValue ExcelUpload(Stream File)
        {
            using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents", FileMode.Create))
            {
                int ReadCount = 0;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((ReadCount = File.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
                }
            }

            return new ReturnValue() { IsSuccessfull = true };
        }

        public ReturnValue test(int id)
        {
            return new ReturnValue() { IsSuccessfull = true };
        }
    }
```

**WCF service contract**

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "ExcelUpload.IUploadFile")]
public interface IUploadFile
{
    [OperationContract]
    [DataContractFormat]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
               UriTemplate = "UploadExcel/",
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ReturnValue ExcelUpload(Stream File);
    // TODO: Add your service operations here

    [OperationContract]
    [DataContractFormat]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               UriTemplate = "test/",
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ReturnValue test(int id);
}


// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class ReturnValue
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsSuccessfull { get; set; }
}
```

**WCF service web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="~/UploadFile.svc" service="ExcelUpload.UploadFile"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 sendTimeout="00:05:00" 
                 crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
          <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultEndpointBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ExcelUpload.UploadFile"  behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="defaultEndpointBehaviour" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ExcelUpload.IUploadFile"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
      </authentication>
      <requestFiltering allowHighBitCharacters="true">
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true"/>
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Web application**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="UploadTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Uploading using WCF REST API</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function uploadBlobOrFile(blobOrFile) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://intranet-services.tosama.si/CroSalesExcelUpload/UploadFile.svc/UploadExcel/', true);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', blobOrFile.size);

            xhr.onload = function (e) {
                progressBar.value = 0;
                progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value;
            };

            // Listen to the upload progress.
            var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback.
                }
            };
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };

            xhr.send(blobOrFile);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="filePicker" type="file" name="Package" accept="image/*"/>
    <br />
    <progress min="0" max="100" value="0">0% complete</progress>
    <br />
    <button title="upload" 
            onclick="if (filePicker.files[0]) uploadBlobOrFile(filePicker.files[0])">
        <span>Upload</span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic thing is, why are you trying to create object for **directory**?

@"C:\Users\Public\Documents"

try changing to @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyFile.txt"

Here you can use any type of file instead of txt. 
And don't forget to set limits for your file to be uploaded.

Hope it helps.. !

Comment: Tried this and still the same error. I think there is some trick with permissions, but do not know where. I'we read something about impersonation and delegation, but did not quiet figure it out yet.

Comment: Another way is to save your file on server, using FileDialog or similar control. Then you can use the file with full rights.
OS adds some restrictions to directly read file from Local storage like c: etc

Comment: Thank's for pointing that out, but I would like to have a little more generic solution, to upload the files from Windows App, Web app, mobile App etc.

Comment: You can refer: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-files-save-in-folder-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-Download-and-Delete-option.aspx